# android API 18 ble writeCharacteristic not working

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean, gatt

I am working with the new ble api of android 4.3. 
I am able to scan, connect, discover characteristics e.t.c from my LE device.

In case of reading characteristic value, for some characteristics, i am getting responses and for some others i am getting no response.// guessing it's device fault

The problem is with write operation. The device have 2 characteristic with write property. when i am trying to write them  2 cases is occurring in random -

1. *onWriteCharacteristic* is not being called and value is not changed to the device.
2. *onWriteCharacteristic* is being called with *success* status despite the fact that WriteType is set to *WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE*, but still no value change.

Some non-4.3 apps is successfully changing the characteristic values. So it is not device fault i guess.

Any insight or help will be gratefully appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
Here is on snippet of the log, when i am trying to write a characteristic to a device.

```
08-26 10:59:49.181: D/BluetoothGatt(13516): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: 00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-26 10:59:49.181: D/BtGatt.GattService(1082): writeCharacteristic() - address=CC:AB:96:49:4C:9F
08-26 10:59:49.181: D/BtGatt.btif(1082): btif_gattc_write_char
08-26 10:59:49.181: D/BtGatt.btif(1082): btgattc_handle_event: Event 1015
08-26 10:59:49.181: D/BtGatt.btif(1082): btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 4
08-26 10:59:49.181: D/BtGatt.GattService(1082): onWriteCharacteristic() - address=CC:AB:96:49:4C:9F, status=0
08-26 10:59:49.181: I/MainActivity(13516): Writing characteristic Initiated for Alert Level:true
08-26 10:59:49.191: D/BluetoothGatt(13516): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=CC:AB:96:49:4C:9F UUID=00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Status=0
08-26 10:59:49.191: I/MainActivity#onWrite(13516): Immediate Alert Service characteristic - Alert Level value in string:  value in hex: 02
```

WriteType is set to WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE, but i am still getting the onWriteCharacteristic call, and yet, the value is not changed to the device.

Can anyone help, please?

**EDIT 2:**
I was testing the app with a nexus-4 and still have the same issue with this phone, but hey, the code works fine on Samsung S4 and it is able to write characteristic value on LE device. 
Is it a issue with Nexus-4 then? but  [this guy here says he was able to write with Nexus-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870189/android-4-3-bluetooth-low-energy-unstable?rq=1).