# How to continuously get RSSI without connecting to the BLE device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

My application needs to constantly get RSSI value of a bluetooth device to make some distance-rssi approximation, **without connecting**. However, callback method of the `BluetoothAdapter` gets the RSSI only once when the device scanned.

```
// Device scan callback
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ...
            }
        });     
    }   
};
```

As a solution, I created two `Runnable` objects. One is for starting, other is for stopping scan process. These two objects call each other continuously until I get my desired RSSI value. After that my `Handler` removes them from message queue.

```
private Runnable startScan = new Runnable() {       
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
        scanHandler.postDelayed(stopScan, SCAN_INTERVAL);
    }               
};

private Runnable stopScan = new Runnable() {        
    @Override
    public void run() {         
        bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);                                            
        scanHandler.postDelayed(startScan, STOP_INTERVAL);          
    }
};
```

This seems to be working but I want to know if there is more viable option to do this without connecting.

Comment: This seems to be the right way for me.. Scanning will stop automatically, so after scanning, just start it again...

Comment: This is the proper way. By the way, the scanning behaviour DEPENDS on your android device,for example : Galaxy S4 is firing the scan callback continuously for the same peripheral, while Nexus 7 report only once.

Comment: Forget to mention in some situation even on Nexus 7 the scan callback will fire repeatedly. This only happens for certain peripherals and I haven't find out why they are triggering multiple scan callbacks.

Comment: How to Handle this situation above solution work great with nexus device but it will not discover for samsung galaxy s3.

Answer (score 1):

If the ble beacon is advertising and not connectable, onLeScan is called continously.
If the ble beacon is connectable, the feature depends on the device.