# android beacon library issue in s3 with crash resolver

Tags: android, bluetooth

i am working on beacon BLE Library of radius networks.
while working of scanning on leScanCallback it shows alert "Unfortunately, Bluetooth Share has Stopped" after inserting bluetooth crash resolver class and implementing in service it shows warning of **"BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED never received.  Recovery may fail."**

Answer (score 0):

That warning indicates that your operating system was commanded to start a bluetooth discovery (needed to clear out the bluetooth device list) but it did not do so.

It is possible that the operating system callback just failed and the discovery process will nevertheless succeed in clearing out the list of bluetooth devices.

Comment: then how to acheive that.actually i am using that bluetoothCrashResolver.notifyScannedDevice(device, myLeScanCallback); statement in lescancallback and i am having 30 beacons in range in android callbacks are coming so fast it full that stack of bluetooth.where i suppose to put that code of cleaning bluetooth stack.it shows that message after every 15 sec.

Comment: are you using the Android Beacon Library?  Or are you using the standalone `BluetoothCrashResolver.java` class in your app?  Instructions on using the standalone class are here:  https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/bluetooth-crash-resolver/blob/master/README.md

Comment: i have used that code in lescan.it there any way to add scan period in lescan callback.