# ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads, scanning

I have given reading to understand and try BLE scanning filter issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196114/2624806). and finally I found [ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.html#CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES) that say "Trigger a callback for every Bluetooth advertisement found that matches the filter criteria" but problem remain same. For mention device [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196114/2624806) it still filtering duplicate advertise packet.

Any suggestion if any specific filter need to apply.

Following I tried:

```
ScanFilter deviceFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName("my_device_name").build();

                settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                        .build();
                filters = new ArrayList<>();
                filters.add(deviceFilter);

                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)`