# Android Bluetooth device scanned only one time

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an Android app that needs to connect to a Bluetooth Low Energy device.

The app is working correctly on most devices but i had troubles with some devices (One plus One with Cyanogene Android 4.4.4 and Sony C5303 with Android 4.3) using [BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)).

With the One plus, the problem seems to be the same as related in this post: [Android 4.3: BLE: Filtering behaviour of startLeScan()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502853/android-4-3-ble-filtering-behaviour-of-startlescan) the Bluetooth device is only scanned once. If I connect then disconnect from the device, it is not scan it again.

After some test I tried using: [BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery()) in addition to [BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)).

It appears that my device is now correctly scanned multiple times and my LeScanCallback is correctly called. I can then connect/disconnect from my BLE device.

Question is:
How [BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery()) can interact with [BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)) to allow my device being detected multiple times ?

Thanks for you help !

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: If i remember correctly i wasn't calling 'stopLeScan()' correctly.
After adding stopLeScan my device was detected correctly.

Comment: it's happening with me same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calling 'stopLeScan()' correctly. After adding stopLeScan your device should be detected correctly.