# Getting different byte[] scanRecord data for same BLE device while scanning with different versions of android device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
private final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
       }
 }
```

> I scanned a single BLE device from Acer table of version 4.4.2 and Nexus 7 5.1 version. I want to filter the BLE devices using UUIDS, but I am getting different scanRecord data for same BLE device.

I attached the detailed pics.[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty common in BLE world. When a BLE device ***advertises*** multiple ***services*** - The scanner is free to ***filter*** what it needs or is relevant to it. I have seen similar behavior in a HRM (Heart Rate Monitor) device which doubles up as a Food Pod (profile - RSCP) as well - Hence implementing 2 services at the same time.

For such devices (hosting multiple services) it is a good practice to have a type resolution policy for BLE scan results - for example this may be an order of precedence:-

```
1. GAP Appearance  
2. GATT Service
```

The fitness sensor I mentioned above ([TICKR RUN from Wahoo](http://www.wahoofitness.com/devices/heart-rate-monitors/tickr-run-running-monitor)) sets GAP appearance to 833 belt type HRM and advertises 2 UUID s- HRP and RSCP. So going by sheer scan (advertisement) results we concluded it to be a HRM device only. Only after you connect to it for retrieving GATT services you get the full set of GATT UUIDs and it turned out to support **RSCP** (Running Speed and Cadence Profile) and **HRP** (Heart Rate Profile)

Now from the perspective of scanning - it's a costly game to connect to each and every device in the discovery phase hence it might be OK to go with the **primary** service the device is advertising

HTH!