# Find out connection interval in ble android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How do you find out the connection interval in android once connected to the peripheral using ble? I want to display the value of the connection interval on the screen. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android BLE Connection time interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398766/android-ble-connection-time-interval)

Comment: No, that question is about setting the connection interval.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

There is no Android API available to request the current connection interval. If you are the creator of the peripheral, you could add a characteristic that the peripheral updates when the connection interval changes, which can then be read from the phone.