# android ble connect slowly

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing an Android app to connect to a BLE peripheral device. Android 4.4.2, Galaxy Nexus.

I have an LED on the device to indicate connection state.

The issue is the duration from **connectGatt()** call to the point of receiving onConnectionStateChange `STATE_CONNECTED` are so inconsistent. Some time it is very quick but most of the time it takes 5s or more. Turning Bluetooth off/on does not have any effect.

I tried *TI BTool* on PC with the *TI BLE* Dongle and it always establishes a connection very quickly.

I also tried with an iPhone 5S and it is fast too.

1. Any one has experienced this issue too?
2. Is there any chance we can improve this?

Comment: OK, I found the cause, I think I misused the APIs:

Previously I call **connectGatt** with the 2nd param = true

    connectGatt(context, true, gattCallback);

But now I change it to 

    connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback);

And the connecting time improved greatly

Comment: i already set connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback) but still taking 4-5 second to connect with ble device

Answer (score 63):

Passing true to connectGatt() autoconnect argument requests a background connection, while passing false requests a direct connection. BluetoothGatt#connect() always requests a background connection.

Background connection (according to Bluedroid sources from 4.4.2 AOSP) has scan interval of 1280ms and a window of 11.25ms. This corresponds to about 0.9% duty cycle which explains why connections, when not scanning, can take a long time to complete.

Direct connection has interval of 60ms and window of 30ms so connections complete much faster. Additionally there can only be one direct connection request pending at a time and it times out after 30 seconds. onConnectionStateChange() gets called with state=2, status=133 to indicate this timeout.

I have verified this behavior on Nexus5 but obviously YMMV.

I should mention that there is a race condition in BluetoothGatt.java that can cause a direct connection request even if autoconnect=true is passed into BluetoothDevice#connectGatt().

Comment: It would be amazing if Android's documentation actually mentioned any of this, at all.  It's sort of important.

Comment: Detailed description of the race condition that causes a direct connection instead of background: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69834

Comment: I've just noticed, that my Sony Xperia (D5803) running Android 5.0.2 doesn't call "onConnectionStateChange" with status=133 and newState=Connected but calls instead "onConnectionStateChange" with newState=Disconnected.

Comment: Til 2016-08-09 there is nothing close to this answer on the official documentation. Yet, the timeout now seems to receive a 'disconnected' signal.

Comment: This was super useful. Just changed this and drastically improved the connection speed.

Answer (score 2):

I've experimented slow connection but only when attempting to reconnecting the remote device, connecting device at first time gets no problem but reconnecting remains the connection in the onClientRegistered() method

Comment: I am facing exact same issue, please post the answer