# Android GATT Services returns Null after many successful connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an Android app which connects to the BLE devices, Device does connect most of the time and i am able to capture the readings. But sometime after many connects disconnects, Bluetooth On/Off, my `BluetoothGattCallback` class method

```
onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)
```

with status 0 [which means GATT_SUCCESS].

now when i try to get the BluetoothGattService  like:

```
BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(getServiceUUID());
```

it return null, so that i am unable to perform next steps.
Please help me to find the problem.

Comment: If you can't understand, in what context question has been asked, please don't put your concern here. As i am seeing two users has downgrade this question. If you want more info about the ques, just ask and add comment. This type of behavior is not a professional outlook. So please maintain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to first discover all services for the given device, otherwise when you run `BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(getServiceUUID());` it will return null.

I would recommend you add the `onServicesDiscovered` function and use `gatt.discoverServices();` instead.

```
@Override
    // New services discovered
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Service UUID Found: " + gattService.getUuid().toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hello because of bluetooth low energy is [unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870189/android-4-3-bluetooth-low-energy-unstable) . and as your question define that you get call back function with 0 status code. then instead of using getServivce(UUID). you can use  [getServices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#discoverServices%28%29) method to discover avaliable services. this might be uuid issue!! Maybe you've got the UUID wrong..

Comment: UUID is correct as i am able to get the services, but as i mention after 7 attempts of on/off BT or connect disconnect the device, both getService with UUID and getServices() returns null.