# BLE 4.3 having issue with Service Discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing BLE application for android 4.3+ devices. Device discovery, Device Connecting and then Service Discovery everything fine for Nexus4 4.3 device. But same sequence not working, after establish connection, it not able to discover services.

What I understand till now is, it should work flawlessly for every android device who support BLE4.0 and has Android OS version 4.3+. Is there anything depend on Hardware or any other device specification. [Here](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble112-bluetooth--smart-module/) it also support same, it should not be different.

Answer (score 0):

You should call Discovery services once right after your GATT-client connected. If it is failed, this may mean your device possibly lost bonding (often case). At all [Android BLE critical unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870189/android-4-3-bluetooth-low-energy-unstable) yet.

Comment: This is same I am doing ...n it working for some of device I tested Nexus-4, Moto-G. But on some device it get failing..any other suggestion!!!

Comment: @Shubh and what logcat say?

Comment: @Shubh this log say me nothing, sorry

Comment: let me know what u need,..might be help you.

Comment: @Shubh do you make device bonding?

Comment: yes device connection is build but while service discovery it getting fail.

Comment: @Shubh it could be device brain damage or smartphone BLE bug. In both cases it is unpossible to workaround, sorry

Comment: yes @Konopko , yes similar since peripheral device working with mob device properly so nothing from device side. So I also assuming it is related with smart device, but how can identify it even iat runtime, so can say "Oyyii...there is some issue here"..please suggest if you have any. Thanks :)

Comment: @Shubh if you get some issue, so that is the reason, guess)

Comment: but these issue not responded back to application e.g. some runtime issue.

Comment: @Shubh listen, I'm not sure what exactly damaged in Android BLE: OS or smart device. But it is seems that someth wrong with OS because so many smart devices doesn't work correctly. See the link behind I mentioned.

Comment: yes I am aware about issue mention over there, but I think it's time to conclude as we both not know what could be possible cause, is it OS(that I don't think, but yes customization can play role here) or  Device(but not sure since BLE hardware is same for everyone I guess)...thanks for your time..please update here if you found anything useful. :)

Comment: @Shubh it is new Android L comes this fall, hope it solve BLE problems)

Comment: @Shubh yes, see the last Google I/O 2014