# Break the BLE after connection to BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an Android application able to connect to a BLE (Bluetooth low energy) device.

Problem is after connection, when I want to re-connect to an other device, I can't.
The only solution is to off and on phone bluetooth.

(On the iOS app, it works so problems is from Android app).

I get this error :
    BLE connection generic error

I there any known bug on Android >=4.0 on BLE connections ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 4.3 Bluetooth Low Energy unstable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870189/android-4-3-bluetooth-low-energy-unstable)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of [bugs in the bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=BLE&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&cells=tiles) and the documentation and example are not good.

You have not given enough information to really be able to tell what your specific problem is but the main issue people fall over is thinking that because the api calls are asynchronous you can just use them that way.  In practice you need to use them in a synchronous manner e.g. wait for one call to finish before issuing the next.  I am not clear if this is by intention of just a buggy implementation but it is the case at the moment.

There are definite issues in the underlying framework / drivers as you can get the system into a state where it want allow Bluetooth to switch off, it want work without switching Bluetooth off and on again, it want work without rebooting your phone, it want work reliably with Wifi enabled.  If you go through the bugs list you will find more.

In my opinion it's not at beta standard yet but we have been trying to live with it for the past 9 months and Google look to of stopped working on it as far as I can tell from the updates we have had since the initial release.