# Device is getting disconnected from GATT server

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Android BLE Issue

Once my Device received data from GATT server, After one time received data its getting disconnected. or unable to receive notifications. I tried number of different ways but nothing works.
 I have read the whole url also..
[Android 4.3 Bluetooth Low Energy unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870189/android-4-3-bluetooth-low-energy-unstable)

Answer (score 5):

This problem is solved after a lot of efforts . I was problem that after one time reading characteristic  application getting disconnecting from the GATT server. Now i put the solution : In BLE service class onCharacteristicsRead method i set

setCharacteristicNotification(
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled)

to true. and this works fine for me..

Comment: I already have passed this, but still sometime i am getting disconnected.
Can you please suggest me some workarounds?

Comment: Sometimes mean @JadavLalit can you give me some logs. or particular case or error number ...

Comment: it give me connected state 0 and status 133 everytime, but some times it connects regularly

Comment: gatt server 133 may cause number of cases. You can paste bit snippet of code here to help and understand your issue. in case you can connect me via skype: deepak.kumar3038