# Bluetooth Low Energy Scan Fails Immediately

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to build an app which uses BLE.  I am testing this app on a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 5.0.1.  When I try to scan for bluetooth devices I immediately get this in the log:

```
03-25 17:39:41.235 2696-2714/com.example.multiplayertest D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
03-25 17:39:41.245 2696-2696/com.example.multiplayertest I/System.out: -99
03-25 17:39:41.245 2696-2696/com.example.multiplayertest I/System.out: failed
```

The scan fails immediately with error code -99.  I have not been able to find what this means anywhere and any help you can give would be appreciated.

Scanning Code:

```
    final BluetoothLeScanner scanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    final ArrayList<ScanFilter> filterList = new ArrayList<>();

    ScanFilter.Builder scanBuilder = new ScanFilter.Builder();
    scanBuilder.setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(serviceUuid));
    filterList.add(scanBuilder.build());

    ScanSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
    settingsBuilder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED);

    scanner.startScan(filterList, settingsBuilder.build(), scanCallback);
```

And scanCallback:

```
ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        System.out.println("Result");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
        System.out.println("Results");

    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
        System.out.println(errorCode);
        System.out.println("failed");

    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have these permissions declared in your Manifest - BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ?

Comment: Yes, I have all of those permissions and the result is the same

Comment: Check out this thread - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870189/android-4-3-bluetooth-low-energy-unstable/18889509

It has some comoon problems with BLE and the solution for them.

Comment: I found that thread before and unfortunately it did not help me resolve the issue

Comment: Make sure "Android Settings > Location" is "On"