# Android BLE Slows down after sometime

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im facing a problem on Android and ble peripheral. I connect to a BLE peripheral and exchange dozens of packets (say 300) in approximately 20-30 seconds and then communication start becoming slower and slower, eventually start taking 1.5sec to write a characteristic and getting back its response. This amount of time is not acceptable for my application.

If I disconnect and reconnect after every few hundred packets and resume process from there than it never slows down nor stop working, but this ain't a solution Im looking for.

Is this issue is related to limit of packets per connection or time duration for connection. Any comment will be of great help.

P.S: I have already done what is written over [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889509/1723819)