# Android BLE : Retrieve service UUID in onLeScan() callback when advertised from iOS Peripheral

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Nexus 4(4.4 kitkat) as central and iPad as peripheral.Peripheral has a service which it is advertising.The advertising packet has some data(22bytes) + service UUID.When I try to scan for the peripheral from Android, iPad peripheral is discovered.However when I try to get the service UUID from scanRecord parameter in the callback, I could not find it.All I get is the 20byte data which the peripheral is sending.When I try to scan for devices with the UUID I am not able to discover those peripherals.

Following is the iOS code to advertise a service.The service id being used is "0000192f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

```
CBUUID *serviceUuid = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID];
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[serviceUuid],
                                               CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:[[BTLEConfigs sharedBTLEConfig] getAdvertizingUUID]}];
```

The device gets discovered when I scan without service UUID.

```
// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //-- how to retrieve the service id from scanRecord
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The services are discovered between two iOS devices but between Android device and iOS peripheral its not working.How to scan a peripheral with 16bit service UUID?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i also would like to find a solution to this.

Comment: Finally I was able to get the service UUID from the scanRecord.This link helped me - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19060589/662025.But still I wonder how to scan the sensors with 16bit UUIDs.

Comment: Have you tried using TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID=@"192f" ?

Answer (score 8):

The scan record byte array contains EIR formatted data. See the [Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737) section 8.

The scan record contains one or more sequential EIR entries, which have the following format:

```
<entry length (1 byte)> <data type (1 byte)> <data (length - 1 bytes)>
```

You are looking for an EIR entry with a type of 0x02 or 0x03 (see [Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737) section 18.2). The data for the entry will contain one or more UUIDs in Little Endian format.

Example scan record:

```
02011a0303b4540a094c69676874426c7565
```

Can be broken down into:

```
02 01 1a                    Flags               - 1a
03 03 b454                  16-bit service UUID - 54b4
0a 09 4c69676874426c7565    Local name          - LightBlue
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Android BLE -the filtering only works with 16bit UUID not full 128bit.

See [Google issue 58931](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58931)