# getUUIDS returns null when device isn't paired

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetoothadapter

For some strange reason i can't get the uuids of a device i'm getting after a discovery.
But if I paire both device before the discovery, then the method getUUIDS doesn't return null.

Am I Missing something

```
                device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
                ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
                
                if (uuids != null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Not null");
                }
```

Comment: I think this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925789/android-device-getuuids-returns-null

Comment: i've seen it, sadly i'm using bluetooth and not BLE, and i can't use ble in my case