# development: motoactv (rooted) bluetooth scan (no results found)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, watch, motorola

:Hello everybody, i finally figured out how to develop on the motorola watch and just ran into an issue. My app tries to scan for nearby bluetooth devices, but no results were found. At first i thought it was kind of an coding problem, but when i tested it on other devices there was no problem at all. So my questions are:

- Anyone of you ever tried to use the motoactv for development?
- Maybe did anyone know how to solve this issue?
- Is it possible to search for different devices than sensors or headsets?

Some help would be really appreciated :)

Regards mrcoffee85

Answer (score 0):

When i had the same issue on samsung devices i solved it using remove filter from scanning . because some device not supporting 128 bit uuid for scanning. Please read below link for more info 
[startLeScan with 128 bit UUIDs doesn't work on native Android BLE implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019161/startlescan-with-128-bit-uuids-doesnt-work-on-native-android-ble-implementation)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that the rooted motoactv only supports API Level 10 (but of course your right it uses ble). I don't know how motorola does it, but i think there has to be an internal wrapper or something... Any other ideas?