# How to parse 128bits uuids for bluetooth service?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I want to scan for a specific bluetooth device with his 128bits service uuid.

It seems that there are some issues so I'm using this function to parse my uuid.

[startLeScan with 128 bit UUIDs doesn't work on native Android BLE implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019161/startlescan-with-128-bit-uuids-doesnt-work-on-native-android-ble-implementation/21986475#21986475)

My uuid is : ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-fffffffffff0 and 
the byte[] I declared is :byte[] adv = new byte[]{(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,
            (byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xf0};

However, the method startLeScan(uuid[],callback) takes an array instead of List used in the parse function.

So if I put startLeScan(parseUUID(adv),mScanCallBack)), I got en error.. since parseUUID function isn't UUID[] type.

Do you know how can I fix it ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should create an array from your list and then use that.

This may help:

[Convert list to array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java)

Comment: Now I have something like : (UUID[])parseUUIDs(adv).toArray() but still doesn't filter well. Is my byte[] array ok  according to my uuid ?